# Magento add to cart issue

Tags: php, magento, session, cookies

I am facing problem in magento. When adding products to cart, it successfully adds one item but when I try to add another item it removes the previous item and adds the new item. This is because the quote id changes every time, with closing browser or anything else.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked permission on var/session folder?

Comment: yes i tried by setting 777 to both var and var/session folders but no luck.

Comment: There a lot of cases, so need to check all extensions, try do disable them one by one and check, also check cookie life time which set from admin

Comment: check how you create sales quote. is it not logged in or logged in? clear cache?

Comment: that means every time quote has been create.check  session and cookie settign at admn

Comment: yeah quote re create each time.. these are settings
Cookie Lifetime  = 3600
 
, Cookie Path =null ,
 
Cookie Domain =null, 
 
Use HTTP Only   =Yes,
 
Cookie Restriction Mode =  No

Comment: @sergio: I tired by disable the extension but again no success

Comment: the problem is with sessions it regerate everytime,  any idea  how to stop session from regenating ??

Answer (score 0):

you can debug in this function

app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php

and find this function

```
 public function save()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_save_before', array('cart'=>$this));

    $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
    $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
    $this->getQuote()->save();
    $this->getCheckoutSession()->setQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId());
    /**
     * Cart save usually called after changes with cart items.
     */
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_save_after', array('cart'=>$this));
    return $this;
}
```

you can debug here.  hope this will help you.

I have edit this code for custom price

```
      public function save()
                          {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_save_before', array('cart'=>$this));
        $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
                    $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
                    $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();

                   // $this->getQuote()->save();
                    if(isset($_POST['product']))
                    $pid=$_POST['product'];

                    if(isset($_POST['npn']))
                    $new_price=$_POST['npn'];

                    foreach($this->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {    
                        $productId = $item->getProductId();     
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                        if(isset($pid))
                        {
                        if($productId==$pid)
                        {
                        if(isset($_POST['npn']) && $_POST['npn']!='')
                        {
                        $price = $_POST['npn'];
                        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                        // we need this since Magento 1.4
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                        }
                        }
                        }
                    }  
                    $this->getQuote()->save();
                    $this->getCheckoutSession()->setQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId());
                    /**
                     * Cart save usually called after changes with cart items.
                     */
                    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_save_after', array('cart'=>$this));
                    return $this;
                }
```

hope it will help you !!!

Comment: echo($this->getQuote()->getId());exit; value increase by one by clicking add to cart button

Comment: How can i set quote id custom which apply on  whole site ?

Comment: echo($this->getQuote()->getId());exit; value increase by one by clicking add to cart button .. which means session re generate everytime.. any idea  how to stop session from regenating

Comment: The problem is with this function: 
  public function getQuote()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {   /// this retrun false so it set new,,,
            $this->setData('quote', $this->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
it seems some where the valuse got unset ,,,